# Extract the style information from another file

Tags: styles, mapserver

Good afternoon.

I'm trying to get the information from my STYLE LAYERS of mapfiles be drawn from some other .list file but I can not do this. The reason I want it is not having to change the STYLE of all mapfiles when I want to make some minor amendments in mapfiles.

For example, below I have the information given STYLE LAYER, but I would draw this other file information.

```
STYLE


    COLOR 160,160,100
       END STYLE #
       STYLE
         OUTLINECOLOR 100 100 100
         WIDTH 1
       END STYLE #
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the INCLUDE object in my map files to do that.  I create small snippets of mapfiles:

```
  STYLE
    SYMBOL 'square'
    COLOR 0 0 0
    SIZE 24
  END #Style
```

name them something like "_house_style.map".  I put a leading underscre so I know it is just a snippet.

Then include them with

```
INCLUDE "_house_style.map"
```